# SSIS - how to make a connection string for your database server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

How do i make a connection string for my database server ? I want to know this so that i can save connection strings in a table and then use them later. Note - All my database servers don't need password and username. I login to a remote "mother" server and access the other  remote servers in management studio using 'windows authentication'. So, i don't think my connection string needs to have a user name and password.

Comment: I think you want to setup package configuration which can either be xml or SQL based. I've used it to setup different connection strings for our dev, test and production environments. Or do you mean you want to change source and destination databases in a DFT i.e. loop over a load of different data sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is for SSIS, create a connection manager, then poke around in it's properties - you'll find the connection string. Take a look here for examples:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: does not work for me. have tried it already. but, its one of the possible solutions. So, I accept it as an answer.

Comment: _does not work_ does not work for me either. Thanks for the answer, but exactly what problem did you have?

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to an MS SQL database you require to log in using an account.  I am assuming that the windows account you use to connect to the remote server is also the account that is used to log into server is the same account that is used to log into the server.  So you can set a connection manager using the same window authentication.

To set up a new connection from BIDS open the solution manager window, then one right hand mouse click on 'Connection Managers' and left hand mouse click on 'New Connection Manager'
[image: Add new connection manager]

The 'Add SSIS Connection Manager' window will appear, this example l have selected and OLE DB connection, next click on the 'Add..' button.

[image: Add SSIS Connection]

The next screen may already have connections defined as the screenshot shows.  Press the 'New..' button to add another data connection.[image]

This final screen is where you provide the details of the database you wish to connect to.  The combo box titled 'Server name' when you click on the down arrrow, may contain the server\database instance you want to create a connection for.  Otherwise you can enter it manually by typing it directly in the the box.  The syntax is as follows [database server name][MS Sql server instance name]  eg Yoda\LukeDB.  Where 'Yoda' is the name of the server and 'LukeDB' is the name of the database instance you want to connect to.  In the screenshot the 'Log on to the server' is set to 'Use Windows Authentication'.  However this assumes the windows account on you access the remote server with is the same as the machine running the SSIS package.  Once you have entered all the details, press 'Test Connection' to check if a connection can be made successfully.
[image: Enter database connection details]

From a security point of view it would be recommended to set up a SQL account on the database instance which the SSIS package is run against.  Then configure that SQL account just the permissions it requires to run the SSIS package.

Comment: Thats not exactly what i meant, but thanks for posting the images.

Comment: Sorry re-read question and had slap head moment ! Try this http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/